# How do I set up a locally run proxy?

Tags: networking, macos, proxy

I'd like to set up a [node proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) and run it locally on my computer. However, how do I configure my settings so that the local proxy server's requests go through to their destination but all other applications' requests route through the proxy server?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.5 and the configuration settings look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[SquidMan](http://squidman.net/squidman/)** is software for Macs which can turn all the incoming requests to proxy requests and pass the traffic to an end point.

> SquidMan is a MacOS X graphical installer and manager for the Squid proxy cache. It is designed to operate as a "personal" proxy server.
>
> When you run Squid on a MacOS X computer, it can:
>
> - cache downloaded content, reducing network traffic and improving browsing performance on slow links
> - act as a proxy server for other computers on your subnet
> - restore the operation of some MacOS X applications that normally fail through authenticated proxy servers